# If $B⊆E$ is compact and $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ has no accumulation point in $E\setminus\{x_0\}$, an infinite net in $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ tends to $x_0$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This should be rather simple and hold in more generality: If $B\subseteq\mathbb C$ is compact and $B\setminus\{0\}$ has no accumulation point in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, why does it follow that every infinite sequence (and/or every infinite net) in $B\setminus\{0\}$ converges to $0$?

I guess this question can be more generally formulated as follows: If $(E,\tau)$ is a topological space, $x_0\in E$, $B\subseteq E$ is $\tau$-compact and $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ has no $\left.\tau\right|_{E\setminus\{x_0\}}$-accumulation point, then every infinite sequence (and/or every infinite net) in $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ converges to $x_0$. Maybe we need to assume Hausdorfness. Or that $\tau$ is metrizable.

**EDIT**: The situation I've got in mind is $B=\sigma(T)$ for some compact linear operator $T$ on a complex Banach space $X$. It is known that $B\setminus\{0\}$ is closed and discrete in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and the spectral theorem asserts that an enumeration of the eigenvalues is either finite or tends to $0$.

---

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a topological space, $\mathcal N_\tau(x):=\{N\subseteq E:N\text{ is a }\tau\text{-neighborhood of }B\}$ for $x\in E$ and $B\subseteq E$. Remember that $x\in E$ is called $\tau$-accumulation point of $B$ if $$\forall N\in\mathcal N_\tau(x):B\cap N\setminus\{x\}\ne\emptyset. \tag1$$ Moreover, $(E,\tau)$ is called accumulation point compact if every infinite subset of $E$ has a $\tau$-accumulation point. It can be shown that if $(E,\tau)$ is compact, it is accumulation point compact as well.

Comment: Are you sure you are not omitting some details? In $\Bbb C$, let $B := \{0, 1\}$. Then $B$ is compact and $B \setminus \{0\} = \{1\}$ has no accumulation points in $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$. But the sequence $(1)_{n = 1}^\infty$ in $B \setminus \{0\}$ *does not* converge to $0$.

Comment: @0XLR Maybe I do. I've added the particular situation which led me to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assume that $B$ is infinite in order to draw any interesting conclusions; with that added assumption you can get a result along the lines that you want.

The space $E$ here is really irrelevant. You have a compact space $B$ and a point $x_0\in B$ such that $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ has no accumulation point in itself. This means that $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ is a relatively discrete subset of $B$. If $B$ is infinite, compactness of $B$ implies that every open nbhd of $x_0$ is cofinite in $B$: if $x_0$ had an open nbhd $U$ such that $B\setminus U$ were infinite, $\{U\}\cup\big\{\{x\}:x\in B\setminus U\big\}$ would be an open cover of $B$ with no finite subcover.

Let $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be any sequence of **distinct** points of $B\setminus\{x_0\}$. If $U$ is an open nbhd of $x_0$, then $\{y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\setminus U$ is contained in the finite set $B\setminus U$, so there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $y_n\in U$ for all $n\ge n_0$, and the sequence therefore converges to $x_0$. Essentially the same argument works as long as each point of the sequence occurs only finitely many times. Without that restriction you may have a sequence with a constant subsequence, even if the original sequence hits infinitely many distinct points of $B\setminus\{x_0\}$, and in that case the original sequence won’t converge to $x_0$. However, the argument does show that every sequence in $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ that hits infinitely many different points of $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ has a **subsequence** converging to $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few questions on your terminology: (a) What do you mean by "relatively discrete"? I guess it means discrete in the subspace topology, but isn't discretness a hereditary property, i.e. isn't $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ discrete in the subspace topology on $B\setminus\{x_0\}$ if and only if it is discrete in the topology on $B$? (b) What's the definition of "cofinite"?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: A subset of a space is *cofinite* if its complement in the space is finite: it is the **co**mplement of a **finite** set. Yes, *relatively discrete* here means discrete in $B\setminus\{x_0\}$. I use that term to emphasize that while no point of the set is a limit point of the set, the set may (and in this case does) have one or more limit points in the space as a whole. In other words, it’s a discrete set in $B$, but it’s not a **closed** discrete set.